# Which Java language mechanisms allow object reference variable types to be different than the type of object it refers to?

Tags: java

The questions asks

"What two Java language mechanisms allow the type of an object reference variable to be "different" than the type of the object to which it refers? Give specific examples to illustrate. In what sense are they not different at all?"

I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly. At first I thought it would be Polymorphism but doesn't that only determine which object a method will reference when there are multiple objects?

Then I think it is upcasting and downcasting. Since that seems like the correct answer.

I am not sure if I am missing another mechanism. Can someone help me clarify this, my book really does not do a good job of explaining this for m.e

Comment: Possibly think of extending and implementing.

Comment: Inheritance hierarchy, and generics... just throwing two terms out there. :) BTW, the TA for this course could just be trolling stack overflow for all you know. Then this would be an honor code violation. :-/ Not fun.

Comment: I'm not sure answering your question outright helps you think this through.  For instance, you say "upcasting" and "downcasting".  Those are verbs, whereas the question speaks of types: nouns.  Casting provides a clue though.  Think about how the original types before casting relate to one another, and how they might be "different", which word (different) significantly is quoted in the original question.

Comment: (Frankly, I'd have trouble deciding which two terms the question expected.  My first guess would be "extends" and "implements", but they could be looking for some different distinction.  I hate questions of this nature.)  (Kinda sounds like the prof wants you to parrot back what you heard in a lecture.)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) although I don't think you understand it correctly. It means that one object can have more than one form. To have more than one form the object must be referred via a different type. There are two ways (at least) that you can make an object such that it can be referred to in multiple ways. As Anthony says, think Extending and Implementing.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say Interface and Inheritance.  Consider...

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...the concrete ArrayList is indeed different than what list is declared to be.

Comment: Oh.  What @Usman-Ismail said.  Think Extending (which is Inheritance) and Implementing (Interface).

Answer (score 0):

See definition for polymorphism.

```
Ability to exist in many forms
```

And the concept it late binding. See this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java